# FindElement does not return element text unless actually in DOM

Tags: selenium, webdriver, knockout.js

I'm using Selenium's webdriver, but I've hit upon a problem.
I'm using KnockoutJS to bind my UI to data from the server.  In my tests when I call `FindElement(By.Id("InputField"))` it is returning the element ok, but unfortunately the Text() field is empty.

When I run a Jquery selector on the field:

`$("#InputField").val()` it gives me the text in the input field ok.

When I inspect the Html source, there is no value in the input field, and I guess this is because KnockoutJS is binding the value to the input field late.

How do I get WebDriver to pull the attributes, text etc. from the field correctly rather than just empty text?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using the `Text` property try using `element.GetAttribute("value")`

```
IWebElement element = _driver.FindElementById("InputField");
string value = element.GetAttribute("value");
```